# C++ protected heritage

Tags: c++, class, protected

I have an abstract class AUnit with variables and getters/setters in virtual pure like this

```
class AUnit {int var... int getVar() const = 0 ... }
```

All the data is in protected: except constructor and destructor.

I have Berserk and Tank as child like this

```
class Berserk : public AUnit
{
...
private:
int getVar() const;
```

In their .cpp, I write the code of the getters and setters. Nothing special.

But I have one other class (foo for example) like this

```
class Foo : public Berserk, public Tank
```

who need to access the data in Berserk or Tank so I changed the private keyword by protected, here is the error :

```
Tank.hpp:36:25: erreur: ‘virtual int Tank::getY() const’ is protected
error inside the context
```

As first, I just tried to access the data with the AUnit getter but cause of virtual pure and abstract concepts, I thought to reinterpret_cast my AUnit in his real type after passing getType of AUnit in non-pure and in public. Still not working, its the scheme I told you earlier.

It's just classical heritage, can I have some help ?

Comment: In ``class Foo : public Berserk, public Tank`` I guess you mean private, right ?

Comment: Can you please 'explain' a little more ? I'm not sure to understand your 'question' and your vision of the problem.

Comment: Sounds like a [diamond of death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem) to me.

Comment: @user2624468: You said you replaced private by protected and I only see public...

Answer (score 1):

Your code snipped is certainly incomplete. My guess is that you have something like this:

```
int Foo::f(Tank const* tank) {
    return tank->getY();
}
```

(probably, you are doing something more interesting with value than returning it).

Even though access to `Tank::getY()` is `protected`, the class `Foo` won't have access to `getY()` in the above code because the object pointed to by `tank` is not known to be a `Foo` object: a class has only access to `protected` members in a base object of its own type! That is, the following would be OK:

```
int Foo::f(Foo const* foo) {
    return foo->getY();
}
```

So far the only good use I have found for `protected` a `virtual` member functions which have a reasonable an non-trivial implementation in a base class and which are called from a [further] derived class as part of overriding the member. This way, functionality can be added and the common logic can be used (of course, any `virtual` function is **not** `public` but rather `private` or `protected`).

Comment: I'm searching corrections thanks to your answer but I have one stupid question to ask. If I have an Animal who can be a Cat so Cat : public Animal. I can't use Animal as a Cat cause its not all time the case but I can manipulate Cat as an Animal always so here Foo is a children of Tank so why cant I use the getters of Tank to manipulate my Foo if they are in protected ? For my use, I don't need the real type, abstract is ok.

Comment: You can do this with the type of *your* type, i.e., `Foo` in this case. But you can't do this with objects whose type isn't statically known to be a `Foo` but which are only known to be of type `Tank`. That is, `protected` access is only granted to members of a derived type for access to objects of that said derived type.

Comment: Sorry but can I use your email to send you my 3 classes to have a concrete idea about how to process to succeed this part ? It's hard to explain using foo etc..

Comment: The approach seems to edit the question to clarify it based on comments and answers. I wouldn't make a commitment to review a mail and respond to it! If you edit your question, others can step in and answer it as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally a bad idea to give the overriding function a stricter access protection than the function it overrides. Consider:

```
class Base {
public:
  virtual void f() {}
};

class Derived : public Base {
private:
  virtual void f() {}  // overrides Base::f
};

Derived d;
d.f();  // error - f is private
Base* pb = &d;
pb->f();  // OK - calls d.f()
```

To avoid such paradoxes, it is prudent to put overrides at the same access level as the original (or the more relaxed access level, though that's somewhat unusual).